# Insert documents into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, insert

I have created this index using PUT http://localhost:9200/task_idx4 on postman:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "sort.field": [ "created_at", "id.raw" ],
            "sort.order": [ "desc", "desc" ]
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "wildcard", "fields": { "raw": { "type": "keyword" }}},
            "current_status": { "type": "keyword" },
            "version_rev":    { "type": "keyword" },
            "tracking_id":     { "type": "wildcard" },
            "invoice_number":  { "type": "keyword" },
            "created_at":     { "type": "date" }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to insert docs into this index using:
PUT http://localhost:9200/task_idx4/_doc

```
{
    "id": "xxxx",
    "current_status": "unassigned",
    "version_rev": "xxx",
    "tracking_id": "xxx",
    "invoice_number": "xxx",
    "created_at": "2021-03-23 11:00:05.054595 +00:00"
}
```

The error returned is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "cluster_block_exception",
                "reason": "index [task_idx4] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"
            }
        ],
        "type": "cluster_block_exception",
        "reason": "index [task_idx4] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"
    },
    "status": 429
}
```

How can I insert docs into my index? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark

The problem here is that you don't have any space left on your harddisk.

You can check with the `df` command, but apparently you're over 95% disk usage, so you need to make some room (ideally below 80%) before you can index data.